# Running a Kind cluster inside a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, kind

I am using Gitlab CI/CD to store and automatically build and unit test most of my code at commit/push.

Outside of Gitlab the code runs in a Kind cluster. Because there is no Kind cluster currently running *IN* the Gitlab CI/CD pipeline I can't test functions that rely on the cluster for services.

Is there a way to run a Kind cluster *IN* a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline?